# The letter 'd' is fatal to my htaccess rewriterule?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'll admit readily, `.htaccess` isn't my greatest strength, especially where `regex` may be involved. (I'm getting better, but still getting there.) Anyway, based off of this [Git on common htaccess commands](https://gist.github.com/ScottPhillips/1721489), I included the following in my `htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^/?Search/([^/d]+)/([^/d]+)/?$ Search.html?searchvariable=$1&searchnumber=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Now, this address

```
http://example.com/Search/Foo/12
```

Will bring up my search page with 12 entries.

But THIS...

```
http://example.com/Search/doo/12
```

will `404` every time. In fact, ANY address with a **d** in my search section it will `404`.

I'm guessing this is somehow due to the `([^/d]+)`, but I *thought* (via regex) that meant any digit or word with the `/d`, but maybe it's being treated like a **not d**?

How do I rewrite it so it's any variable even ones that have the letter d in it?

Answer (score 1):

Risked it...
Rewrote

```
RewriteRule ^/?Search/([^/d]+)/([^/d]+)/?$ Search.html?searchvariable=$1&searchnumber=$2 [L,QSA]
```

as

```
RewriteRule ^/?Search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ Search.html?searchvariable=$1&searchnumber=$2 [L,QSA]
```

And it worked fine. Not sure why the examples I was working from included random 'd's in them... oh well.